# If there are 2 always blocks which block will be executed first

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am new to verilog and I have a question

Suppose I have 2 always blocks in a module, which block will be executed first or will they be executed at the exact same time. If so what is the value of r1. For example

```
module example(clk);
input clk;
reg r1;
always @ (posedge clk)
  r1 <= 1'b0;
always @ (posedge clk)
  r1 <= 1'b1;
endmodule
```

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two `always` blocks create two processes that execute in parallel. Both processes will block waiting for a rising `clk` event. When that event happens, both processes will schedule to resume. However, Verilog/SystemVerilog simulators use an event queue that serializes everything that is supposed to happen simultaneously. There's no way for you to predict which process gets scheduled first; it is a simulation race condition. In practice, one particular version of a simulator will always choose one process before another, so you will always see the same result. But that result might change if you switch to a different tool, or even change some options in the tool for debugging or optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Both always blocks will go simultaneously in parallel, so it is forbidden to assign same reg in two always blocks. In simulation it will probably be undefined, and it will not synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

It is tool dependent. A single reg should not be assigned values in two different always blocks.